# How can I run wildfly in debug mode, as a service on Windows?

Tags: windows, jboss, wildfly

I am running Wildfly as a service on windows. When I need to debug, I am shutting this down and starting Wildfly via `standalone.bat -debug`. What I want is to have the debug switch on always, when it runs as a service?

Comment: Sorry for resurrecting an old topic but it seems the true debug expression has one more dash, namely `standalone.bat --debug`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Uncomment following JAVA_OPTIONS from `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf.bat`

> rem # Sample JPDA settings for remote socket debugging
>
> set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS%
> -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=n"

start service. Now you can detach a debugger with your favorite IDE. If you are using Eclipse you can switch to "Debug-Configurations" and add a new Remote Java-Application.

Comment: It works with Wildfly 23?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using WildFly 11 and uncommenting the following lines in bin\standalone.conf.bat (windows) did the job:

```
set "DEBUG_MODE=true"
set "DEBUG_PORT=8787"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open the command line and set java options with the following debug options:

```
set JAVA_OPTS = -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,suspend=n,server=y
```

start `wildlfy` service by running `standalone.bat` or `standalone.sh` for windows/linux respectively